# Jquery disable a button until two inputs have minimum length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to keep an input disabled until 2 inputs have atleast 4 characters. The closest I was able to find on SO was a user settling for 8 characters total but this would allow for one of the inputs to be blank in the other had over 8. Here is what I have tried:

**Without `on()`**

```
$('#ancestor input').keyup(function(){
  var foo = $('input[name=foo]').val();
  var bar = $('input[name=bar]').val();    
    if(foo.length > 4 && bar.length > 4){  
      $('#some-button').prop('disabled', false);
      }else{
      $('#some-button').prop('disabled', true);
      }  
});
```

**With `on()`**

```
$('#ancestor input').on('keyup',function(){
  var foo = $('input[name=foo]').val();
  var bar = $('input[name=bar]').val();    
    if(foo.length > 4 && bar.length > 4){  
      $('#some-button').prop('disabled', false);
      }else{
      $('#some-button').prop('disabled', true);
      }  
});
```

Interestingly I can `console.log(foo.length)` and `console.log(bar.length)` and see both lengths ticking up just fine with each `keyup`.

Comment: JSFiddle please, any problems you have?

Comment: `At least 4 characters` so should be `>= 4`. **Now**, what is your issue???

Comment: "atleast 4 characters" -> you should've used `>3` instead of `>4`? http://jsfiddle.net/9woyctz2/

Comment: Except for the typo in the > sign, it looks like your stuff was working.

Comment: your code might works, you should use `>3` for atleast four chars

Answer (score 5):

As `A. Wolff` has mentioned, your condition is using `>` instead of `>=`.

```
if (foo.length >= 4 && bar.length >= 4) {
```

---

If you have 2 input elements, you can also invert the condition:

```
$('#ancestor input').keyup(function(){
  var lengthA = $('input[name=foo]').val().length;
  var lengthB = $('input[name=bar]').val().length;

  $('#some-button').prop('disabled', lengthA < 4 || lengthB < 4);
});
```

Conceptually that means "disable if any input is not 4 characters long" instead of "do not disable if both inputs are more than 4 characters long".

Comment: @nicael reverted your change, the opposite of `not( A >= 4 && B >= 4)` is `A < 4 || B < 4`. Is it fine to just edit it back? Don't know yet how to provide feedback "stackoverflow-correctly".

Comment: It's completely fine, because I have been just dumb. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as far as I can see. The only issue is that your condition checks for at least 5 characters, not 4 characters, due to the operator you've chosen to use.

Use a `>=` instead, as this asserts something that is "equal to or greater than".

```js
$('#ancestor input').on('keyup',function(){
  
  var foo = $('input[name=foo]').val();
  var bar = $('input[name=bar]').val(); 
  
  $('#some-button').prop('disabled', !(foo.length >= 4 && bar.length >= 4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ancestor">
  <input name="foo">
  <input name="bar">
  <input id="some-button" type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Might want to have it disabled initially.

Comment: @Ernesto just noticed that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching the jquery object length against a filtered jquery object to see if they are different.

```
$('#ancestor input').on('input keyup change paste', function () {
    var els = $('input[name=foo],input[name=bar]');
    var filtered = els.filter(function(){
       return (this.value.length >= 4); 
    });
    $('#some-button').prop('disabled', (els.length != filtered.length));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9se4x2an/

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, I've been staring at this for 3 hours and it was just a typo (misspelled *length* as *lengh* on one of the variables). Needed more coffee to see it apparently. Thanks to everyone for helping.